# SFML - Applications has stopped Responding

Tags: c++, sfml

So, I'm using CodeLite on Windows, building with Mingw64 on 64 bit system. Everything builds, but when i run the application, it crashes with "Client.exe" has stopped responding. Client.exe being my application. I'm literally running the default example code off the SFML website. When I've googled around for quite some time now and I honestly have no idea as what to even look at for this error.

Sometimes my console will output
Application has exited with error code: 255

But most of the time it outputs:
Program exited with return code: -1073740940

Comment: oh and all compiled sfml dlls are in the folder with the executable.

Comment: Do you have all libraries available for executable at the start of the program? What happens when you start executable without debugger?

Comment: As stated in my comment above, all the compiled SFML libraries are available in the executable's folder. It does not matter if it's with the debugger or without it, no matter which way I launch the application I get the same issue "Client.exe has stopped responding", client.exe being my newly built executable.

Comment: Make sure you don't mix debug and release library and that sfml is built with same compiler that you use to build your Client.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ensured that the debug and release libraries were good (they both use different inclusions either way (sfml-system-s-d for debug, sfml-system-s for release) As for being built on the same compiler, I ensured I was using the Mingw for windows (I have both 32bit and 64bit for each individual build dependent on what architecture I'm building for). I am also using Mingw 32 and 64 bit for compiling (I installed the 32 bit and 64 bit compiler in separate paths just to be safe.

Comment: Well, you may do three things. First: don't build static version, you don't really need it until you publish your application. you may mix static and non-static versions r didn't define SFML_STATIC macro. Second, try building SFML from source with your compiler (plus first). If that doesn't help, try building it with msvc 2015 to ensure that the problem is not in your compiler.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that all a shot. In the mean time, I'm also getting this output when trying to build 32bit. I'm gonna attempt to switch off static and see if I get anything, but here's the console log for reference. I appreciate the help.
http://pastebin.com/DLisF2Nj

Comment: Okay, switching to dynamic libraries seems to have fixed my issue, Now I'm getting problems with entry points, but a quick search has lead me to understand that the Libraries SFML was compiled with has a different version than my compiler. I just need to rebuild SFML for MingW and I'll be good to go. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using help from the comments on my question.

As stated by Satus, The issue was, first, my libraries were statically linked, using the Dynamic libraries, instead, seemed to have fixed my issue. My second issue was that my SFML libraries were built using the wrong version of MingW. Recompiling this was simple enough. I downloaded the SFML source code. Used CMake to set everything up as displayed on the official SFML compiling and building tutorials, and built it using my version of MinGW. After copying the newly compiled DLL's and Debug DLL's, everything worked perfectly.

Be sure if you're using two different version of MingW (64bit and 32bit) to compile each version in CMake accordingly, otherwise you may get issues.